# Conditional aggregate with Group By clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, hiveql

I'm trying to do this with HiveQL but I don't know how to do this in SQL neither. Table structure as follows:

```
id1    id2    category  
123    abc    1
123    def    1
123    def    2
456    abc    1
123    abc    1
123    abc    2
...
```

I'd like to write a query that outputs:

```
key           count     category1count    category2count
123-abc        3               2                 1
123-def        2               1                 1
456-abc        1               1                 0
```

So far I've got this:

```
SELECT concat( concat(id1,'-'), id2), count(*) , 
count( SELECT * WHERE buyingcategory = 1 ??? ) , 
count( SELECT * WHERE buyingcategory = 2 ??? ) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY concat( concat(id1,'-'), id2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT concat(id1,'-', id2) `key`, count(*) , 
 sum( case when category = 1 then 1 else 0 end) category1count , 
 sum( case when category = 2 then 1 else 0 end) category2count
 FROM table1 
 GROUP BY concat(id1,'-', id2)
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83831/11)

Comment: Thanks! Any reason I should worry about perf for using a conditional operation here? This will be run on a large data set (input size of 8-10 GB). But this works great so far, thanks again!