# SQL Query: Count, Group by date and year multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I've got a Table Like following:

```
Date       | Type |
2016/04/01    A
2016/04/01    B
2016/04/02    B
2016/05/07    A 
   ...       ...
```

I try to make a query that count each Type occurence grouped by month/year:

```
DateByYearMonth  |  A  |  B  |
04/2016             1     2
05/2016             1     0
...
```

I tried many things but I couldn't have what I want. My "base query" is:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1) AS A
FROM DBase.dbo.MyTable
WHERE [Type] = 'A'
AND Date BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20160930'
GROUP BY YEAR(Date),
         MONTH(Date)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Your Type column contains only two datas (A, B), fixed n datas (A, B, C, D), or an unknowned number of datas ?

Comment: You'll need to look at [`PIVOT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus It contains fixed n datas

Comment: Conditional aggregation may suffice eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982970/conditional-aggregate-with-group-by-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you could do something like that, using a PIVOT on GROUPED by Year / Month datas.

Of course, you'll have to add the n desired datas for your columns, in the PIVOT and the main select

```
select 
   year, 
   month, 
   coalesce(A, 0) as A, 
   coalesce(B, 0) as B
from 
    (select  
       [Type], 
       Year([Date]) as year, 
       Month([Date]) as month, count(*) c
     from tt1
     group by [Type], Year([Date]), Month([Date])
     ) t

PIVOT(sum(c)
      for [Type] in ([A], [B])
) as pvt
```

Answer (score 3):

the simplest way is to count with `case when` condition:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(MONTH(Date), '/', YEAR(Date)) AS YM ,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS [A] ,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS [B]
FROM    SomeTable
GROUP BY MONTH(Date) , YEAR(Date)
```

output based on your data sample:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [date], 20) AS DATEBYYEARMONTH, 
           Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN type = 'A' THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END)                         A, 
           Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN type = 'B' THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END)                         B 
    FROM   #temp 
    GROUP  BY CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [date], 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try query like this

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
  concat(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(mm, date)), 2), '/', DATEPART(yyyy, date)) AS dt,
  type,
  COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM dates1
GROUP BY concat(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(mm, date)), 2), '/', DATEPART(yyyy, date)),
         type)
SELECT
  dt,
  ISNULL([A], 0) AS [A],
  ISNULL([B], 0) AS [B]
FROM cte
PIVOT (MAX(cnt) FOR type IN ([A], [B])) P
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommended @RaphaëlAlthau's answer. But, if you would like to make it dynamic, please try this.

```
DECLARE @TYPES VARCHAR(MAX),
    @TYPESELECT VARCHAR(MAX)        
SELECT @TYPES = STUFF((SELECT ','+ QUOTENAME(TYP) FROM T1 GROUP BY TYP FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') ;
SELECT @TYPESELECT = STUFF((SELECT ','+ 'ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(TYP)+',0) AS '+QUOTENAME(TYP) FROM T1 GROUP BY TYP FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') ;

EXEC ('SELECT Mnth, '+ @TYPESELECT +'
FROM 
(SELECT  
   [Typ], 
   CAST(YEAR([DateT]) AS VARCHAR) +''/''+CAST(MONTH([DateT]) AS VARCHAR) AS Mnth, 
   COUNT(DateT) C
 FROM T1
 GROUP BY [TyP], YEAR([DateT]), MONTH([DateT])
 ) t
PIVOT(SUM(C)
  FOR [Typ] IN ('+ @TYPES +')
) AS PVT')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version of PIVOT here:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),[Date],103),7) as DateByYearMonth,
            [Type],
            COUNT(*) as Tcount
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),[Date],103),7), [Type]
) as t
PIVOT (
    MAX(Tcount) FOR [Type] IN ([A],[B])
) as pvt
```

Output:

```
DateByYearMonth A   B
04/2016         1   2
05/2016         1   NULL
```